# Why isn't my Akka.NET Stream Subscriber receiving messages?

Tags: c#, .net-core, akka.net, akka.net-streams

I'm am having a go at writing a simple Akka.NET streams flow. The Source is an `IActorRef`. The Sink is a `ISubscriber`. I am using TestKit to implement it as a unit test:

```
[Fact]
public void AkkaStreams_ActorSourcePublisherSink_Works()
{
    using (var materializer = Sys.Materializer())
    {
        var probe = CreateTestProbe();
        var source = Source.ActorRef<HandlerErrorEvent>(10, OverflowStrategy.DropNew);
        var subscriber = new Mock<ISubscriber<HandlerErrorEvent>>();
        var sink = Sink.FromSubscriber<HandlerErrorEvent>(subscriber.Object);
        var graph = source.ToMaterialized(sink, Keep.Both);
        var (actor, publisher) = graph.Run(materializer);

        subscriber.Verify(s => s.OnSubscribe(It.IsAny<ISubscription>()));

        var evnt = new HandlerErrorEvent("", HandlerResult.NotHandled);
        actor.Tell(evnt, ActorRefs.Nobody);

        base.AwaitCondition(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                subscriber.Verify(s => s.OnNext(It.IsAny<HandlerErrorEvent>()));
                return true;
            }
            catch(MockException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The initial `Verify` call on the `OnSubscribe` method passes fine, but the Mock Subscriber never receives a call to `OnNext`.

What am I doing wrong?

Running as `netcoreapp2.0`. References:

```
"Akka.TestKit.Xunit2" Version="1.3.2"
"Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0"
"Moq" Version="4.8.0-rc1"
"xunit" Version="2.3.1"
"xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.3.1"
"dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ISubscriber<>` mock is not compliant to [Reactive Streams specification](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/tree/v1.0.0#specification). It states, that in order to get any message after subscribing, subscriber must first communicate a demand using [ISubscription.Request(long)](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-dotnet/blob/f1a95c626d6d765b19ffc711cae9eb276052ac5e/src/api/Reactive.Streams/ISubscription.cs#L38) method.

In general if you're using Akka.Streams test kit, you don't need to mock subscriptions. Just download [Akka.Streams.TestKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Akka.Streams.TestKit/) to get extension methods for Akka.Streams. This way you'll be able to build a fake subscriber simply by calling `this.CreateManualSubscriberProbe<HandlerErrorEvent>();` inside your `TestKit` class. It contains a [dozens of methods](http://getakka.net/api/Akka.Streams.TestKit.TestSubscriber.ManualProbe-1.html) you can use for assertion.

Example:

```
public class ExampleTest : TestKit
{
    [Fact]
    public void Select_should_map_output()
    {
        using (var materializer = Sys.Materializer())
        {
            // create test probe for subscriptions
            var probe = this.CreateManualSubscriberProbe<int>();

            // create flow materialized as publisher
            var publisher = Source.From(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })
                .Select(i => i + 1)
                .RunWith(Sink.AsPublisher<int>(fanout: false), materializer);

            // subscribe probe and receive subscription
            publisher.Subscribe(probe);
            var subscription = probe.ExpectSubscription();

            // request number of elements to receive, here drain source utill the end
            subscription.Request(4); 

            // validate assertions
            probe.ExpectNext(2);
            probe.ExpectNext(3);
            probe.ExpectNext(4);

            // since source had finite number of 3 elements, expect it to complete
            probe.ExpectComplete();
        }
    }
}
```